# WD My Passport 1 TB Portable SSD Size and Size one Disk big difference

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

On my laptop (mac) i transferred 10gb of data to this 1tb ssd. At 9gb it told me it could not transfer anymore because the disk is full? So im thinking its a fake...

Put the external drive into my desktop (windows) and i can see the size and size on disk of the folder i transferred is way different. 9gb to 900gb.

Is this a fake or am i doing something wrong? The file system is apparently exFat

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in your image, you have 245,646 files which have a total size (= actual data) of 2.65 GB (or rather, GiB).

Each of theses files on average is approximately 10KiB big. (1 KiB is 1 kibibyte, which is 1024 bytes. 1 GiB is 1024^3 bytes).

However, on the disk they appear blown up to 240GiB, which is indicated as "Size on disk".

This means that your disk has a cluster size of about 1MiB, probably 1024KiB: 240GiB ÷ 245,646 = 257,837,498,368÷245,646 = approx. 1,049,630 = approx. 1024KiB

Citing from [here](https://techterms.com/definition/cluster) :

> A cluster, or allocation unit, is a group of sectors that make up the smallest unit of disk allocation for a file within a file system. In other words, a file system's cluster size is the smallest amount of space a file can take up on a computer.

Every file on a disk needs to start at a new cluster, so 245.000 files will occupy at least 245'000 clusters, while any file bigger than your cluster size will occupy more than one cluster: A file which has 1025 KiB will occupy TWO clusters of 1024 KiB!

In other words,every single one of your 10KiB files on the disk occupies 1024KiB! That's why your disk is filling up so fast, your files are occupying one hundred times more space than needed! That's how 9GiB become 900GiB!

To check your current cluster size, in windows: press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type cmd, and then write into the console:

```
wmic volume get driveletter,blocksize
```

The solution is to re-format your disk choosing a smaller cluster size. Usually it's best to keep what the OS suggests you. Normally that's 4096 bytes. But if you want to place so many small files on that disk, consider using a smaller cluster size.

Comment: It's probably using a blocksize that corresponds to the underlying storage blocks to reduce the partial block writes--this will improve performance.  Copying a gazillion tiny files to the drive is going to have horrible write performance.

Answer (score -1):

From the data given, it appears that you were either trying to transfer 900GB to a 1tb drive or 9GB to a 900GB drive.

Also, if the operating system says the drive is full then **the drive is full.**

The best I can say is that you either have a fake or you are transferring a way larger file than you thought. Keep in mind that every operating system reserves a small amount of space on the drive for volume information, the larger the drive, the more space required.

Try transferring everything on the drive off of it then formatting it. Try to use NFTS or exFAT (ideally exFAT), so it is compatible with both mac and windows.

Then add the folder you are trying to transfer into a zip archive and try putting that on the drive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107473/discussion-on-answer-by-tcoder-wd-my-passport-1-tb-portable-ssd-size-and-size-on).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the size of the cluster allocation units. For some unknown reason, WD formats them in some models occupying 1 MEGA (1048576 bytes) when the standard size is 476939 bytes (0.4 megabytes)

Make a copy of your data and reformat the disk.

Comment: This is because the disk is formatted as ExFAT, probably so they can write to MAC as well. Format in NTFS and ready.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the disk is formatted as ExFAT, which uses larger cluster allocation sizes, probably so they can write to MAC as well. Format in NTFS and ready.

Comment: Re-formatting the drive to NTFS would not be useful because then he could not write to it from his Mac.